# Daughter And Wife

Tags: logical-deduction, family

Two friends are sitting on a beach and they saw two women coming towards them. First friend says "Here comes my wife and daughter" and second friend also said the same thing i.e. "Here comes my wife and daughter". Both are not married to same women.
Both are Human beings, no involvement of animals or other living things.

How is this possible ??

Comment: To be fair, it's entirely possible for both friends to have said this. It's only challenging if they were both correct ;)

Comment: Both of them are correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible if

> Wife of one friend, say A, is daughter of the other friend, say B and the daughter of A is wife of B.
>  So, $A$ has $X$ as his wife and $X$ also happens to be $B$'s daughter. $B$ has $Y$ as his wife and $Y$ also happens to be $A$'s daughter.

Comment: That's correct...

Answer (score 12):

The 2 friends could have

> married each others daughter. First friend married his/her friends daughter, making her his/her wife (Captain obvious) and the other lady is his/her actual daughter. and vice versa

Edit: Alternatively

> Both women could be pregnant (with daughters) and each married to one of the friends. This only works if you consider the unborn baby as a daughter already. (technically the unborn babies would not be women yet)

Edit: It could have also possibly been

> that it was one of the friend's wife and daughter. and the other friend decided to engage in a bit of fun by implying that he had potentially fathered the daughter. (locker room talk).

Comment: We can't consider unborn babies.

Comment: Alright, then my first answer stands. Not sure how to do a strikethrough on here. so i won't delete my alternate answer, for historic purposes.

Comment: Are you wrongly assuming that "friends" means "men"?

Comment: Good point. Updated accordingly. Thank you @LeppyR64

Comment: Well, if the answers were not involving **widow/er** then they can be far from the correctness. Courtesy: The same was published in a national news paper as a 'mindbender'.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay, what about divorcee? or multiple marriage society?

Comment: @Dexter, multiple marriage is not an option as per the problem description. Well, divorcee could be.

Comment: You got it right @Mea Culpa Nay

Answer (score 5):

Facetious answers:

> (At least) one of them is mistaken. Friend A has seen their wife and daughter approaching, friend B has mistaken friend A's family for their own at a distance.

2

> The approaching women have the unlikely names of 'My Wife' and 'Daughter'

3

> There's a boat called 'Two women' with the wives and daughters on board

4

> Incest

Comment: could also be two ghosts of dead husbands/wives...

Answer (score 4):

> The friends are a sea captain (sailor, whatever. sea captain sounds more dramatic) and his parrot.
>  The parrot repeats what the captains says.
>  And the captain saw his wife and daughter coming to see him.

Comment: Good one! This would also imply that at least one of them was lying.

Comment: It's not lying if you believe it or if you have no idea of what you are saying

Comment: The puzzle doesn't even make any claim about truthfulness. Nice end-around, Marius.

Comment: Its already mentioned in the questions that no animals are taken into considerations , only human beings are considered.

Comment: It wasnt when i wrote the answer

Answer (score 1):

Probably

> It was an ex-wife for one or both of the men.

Another variant:

> They were both priests. Sometimes priests are called fathers and they speak to people as to "sons" and daughters. So each woman was a wife in secular meaning and "a daughter" in religious meaning.

Comment: then it is no longer 'wife'